# Problem installing Python packages (Windows; Visual Studio/C incompatibility, Jupyter Lab, pip, wheel, exit status 1 and 2)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, pip, jupyter-lab

I use Windows. A long time ago I had installed Microsoft VS, which then - I can't remember if it was automatic or not - installed Python 3.7. I never used it, I was using VS for something else, but the 3.7 [was] contained within the VS directory, I believe. Recently, I installed Jupyter Lab. I had some issues, so I installed Python 3.10 in my main directory. The issues disappeared when I installed Lab a second time.

Now, I can't install pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, etc. There are lots of errors.

Things I tried:

1. pip3 installed the wheel package (since "building from wheel" came up as one of the errors before). Successful installation. `pip3 install wheel`
2. Tried reinstalling pandas (just randomly picked that package to test), no luck. `pip3 install pandas`
3. Uninstalled Python 3.7 and deleted it from the registry.
4. Tried reinstalling pandas, no luck.
5. Noticed in the errors that a lot of issues had to do with C, but I'm novice so I don't really understand them.

I haven't tried uninstalling Jupyter Lab yet. That didn't seem to be the issue (though technically I wanted to install the notebook, but I accidentally installed the lab).

The amount of "errors" is massive, so I don't think I can copy-paste all that here, but I will copy-paste some of the end of the output here.

**Let me know if I can provide more output! Unfortunately cannot embed images as of now.**

> error: Command "...[directory]..." failed with exit status 2

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy

> ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

> WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.3; however, version 21.2.4 is available.

> WARNING: Discarding [link-package]... Command errored out with exit status 1:

> 'C:\Users\jvaug\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\jvaug\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-standalone-pip-xy61pttl_*env_pip*_.zip\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\jvaug\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0n1j1zzl\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=51.0.0' wheel 'Cython>=0.29.21,<3' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.18.3; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version>='"'"'3.9'"'"' and (platform_machine!='"'"'arm64'"'"' or platform_system!='"'"'Darwin'"'"') and platform_machine!='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.2; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.19.2; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'aarch64'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.20.0; python_version=='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'arm64'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'Darwin'"'"'' 'numpy>=1.20.0; python_version=='"'"'3.9'"'"' and platform_machine=='"'"'arm64'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'Darwin'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Ha, realized that Python 3.10 was only released a week ago, so that is likely my problem. I'll try using an older version and if that works, I'll update again here just in case someone else has this issue down the road.

Comment: Yep, it worked! Had to uninstall all my python versions and reinstall 3.9 (I installed 3.9 a couple of days ago after all of the above). Made sure everything was added to my PATH, even deleted the directory I had created a virtual environment in (I did that as well after the above), recreated the directory, and bam it worked!

Comment: Yep, as per this [pyreadiness](https://pyreadiness.org/3.10/) Pandas don't support version 3.10 yet.

Comment: Oh thank you! That is such a good resource. I appreciate you sharing it!